# "Сегодня, 20 июля в 15.00": уточнение ли?

Tags: пунктуация

**Сегодня, 20 июля в 15.00, стартовал уже пятый парад невест в городе Минске.** 
Стоит ли обособлять "22 июля в 15.00"?

Answer (score 1):

В предложении используется уточнение "20 июля". (*когда?* сегодня; а *именно когда*? 20 июля). Его нужно обособить. Выражение "в 15.00" отделять запятой от последующего предложения необязательно, хотя и оно тоже может быть уточнением. Возможны два варианта постановки знаков в этом предложении:

1. Сегодня, 20 июля, в 15.00 стартовал уже пятый парад невест в городе Минске.
2. Сегодня, 20 июля, в 15.00, стартовал уже пятый парад невест в городе Минске.  Постановка запятой после выражения "в 15.00" зависит от интонации и значимости информации, заключённой в этой фразе.

Answer (score 0):

Надо обособить "22 июля". Это уточнение.